# How to delete the symmetric rows of a matrix stored in long format and in one query?

Tags: sql, algorithm, sqlite

I store matrix data in sqlite with a schema of the form:

```
create table mat_long(a varchar, b varchar, float val)
```

I then can store the following matrix:

```
    x y z 
 x  4 1 2
 y  1 4 3
 z  2 3 4
```

using my table, in the following long-format way:

| a | b | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | x | 4 |
| x | y | 1 |
| x | z | 2 |
| y | x | 1 |
| y | y | 4 |
| y | z | 3 |
| z | x | 2 |
| z | y | 3 |
| z | z | 4 |

As you noticed, this matrix is symmetric so I would need to store about only half of it. The problem is I already have this data in a table and must delete the symmetric part. A query to find all the symmetric duplicates would be:

```
select *
from mat_long
where (a, b) in (select b, a
                 from mat_long) and
      a <> b
```

I would like to delete half of them, the correct ones but not sure how to do that in sqlite or sql for that matter.

I would like to run a delete such that my table above ends like this:

| a | b | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | x | 4 |
| x | y | 1 |
| x | z | 2 |
| y | y | 4 |
| y | z | 3 |
| z | z | 4 |

I tried the following but it hangs sqlite:

```
select t1.*
from mat_long as t1
where (t1.a, t1.b) in (select t2.b, t2.a
                       from mat_long as t2
                       where t1.a <> t2.a and
                             t1.b <> t2.b) and
      t1.a <> t1.b
```

Comment: What's the goal?  Saving half the space in a database table is probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that your table is symmetric, you can filter out values whose "*a*" is less or equal than the "*b*" value:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
WHERE a <= b;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gM4JYGFBkcf4BhGuPMcGG/0).

---

If instead you want to use a `DELETE` statement, you can do it as follows:

```
DELETE FROM tab
WHERE a > b;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gM4JYGFBkcf4BhGuPMcGG/1).

Comment: Creating a new table with the rows to _keep_ is likely to be faster (if the matrix is really big).